# Ticks stop early in PGFPlot

Tags: pgfplots, plot, ticks

So I was trying to produce [this](http://i.minus.com/imrvv3iIm35Xm.png) with PGFPlot and got pretty close with the code below but (apart from the major/minor ticks not being as different in their lengths as in the example) I have one problem: The ticks in the y axis stop too early. Is there a way to make them appear without the -16 appearing (since that's the only way I see at the moment)?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,answers,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable,graphicx,tabularx,booktabs,amsmath,amssymb,lmodern,textcomp,gensymb,ifpdf,placeins,wrapfig,xfrac,lastpage,floatrow,setspace,cancel,siunitx,booktabs,array,multirow,ifthen,zref-abspage,zref-lastpage,multicol,bigints,relsize,latexsym,amssymb,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        semithick,
        tick style={semithick}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
y label style={rotate=-90},
xmin=-5, xmax=5, ymin=-16, ymax=5,
ytick={-10,0},
xtick={-5,0,5},
minor x tick num=4,
minor y tick num=9,
axis equal image,
width=12cm
]
\addplot[
black,
domain=-5:5,
samples=101,
]
{x/abs(x)*(abs(x)^(1/3))*abs(x-4)};

\addplot [color=red, thick, dotted] coordinates {(-2,-20) (-2,20)};
\addplot [color=blue, thick, dotted] coordinates {(0,-20) (0,20)};
\addplot [color=red, thick, dotted] coordinates {(1,-20) (1,20)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To make the `-16` not appearing, set `ytick={-16,-10,0}` and then `yticklabels={,-10,0}`, the emptiness before the first comma replaces `-16` in the labels.

I haven't been able to get the minor ticks to work yet though..

Comment: `ytick={-15,-13,...,5}`?

Comment: BTW, with a MWE (minimal working example) please remove all unnecessary packages (hence the *minimal*).

Comment: Yeah thanks. That worked. And I will try removing whatever I can fro now on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the minor ticks to work and to remove the first ytick label, use

```
ytick={-20,-10,0}
yticklabels={,-10,0}
```

Which generates: [image: Eureka]